# Parse data from JSON to SCSS

Tags: json, parsing, compilation, sass, pug

Is possible to feed JSON data to SCSS ?

Currently I'm using jade as a template engine and I use data from a json file, achieving that using gulp-data.

My gulp task is the following:

```
gulp.task('partials', function () {
  "use strict";

  return gulp.src(['dev/templates/*.jade', '!dev/templates/partials/**/*.jade'])

    .pipe(data(function (file) {
      return JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync('./dev/data/globals.json')
      );
    }))

    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/'))

    // Notify browserSync 
    // to refresh
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});
```

And using the data from the json file like this: **#{example.test.name}**

Is possible to use the same thing in SCSS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to directly handle JSON with SCSS alone. Since you're already using Gulp, you can use an third-party tool such as [eyeglass](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass) or [sassport](https://github.com/davidkpiano/sassport) to convert JSON into a SCSS hash. Another tool available is [json-sass](https://github.com/acdlite/json-sass), which you can use standalone.

If you're not using Gulp, then you would have to rely on Gem based converters but they don't seem to be actively maintained:

- https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars
- https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/SassyJSON

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Now I'm using **gulp-json-to-sass**, converting all the data into variables and then use them across the scss project.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two other solutions:

- converting JSON to SASS/SCSS variables: https://github.com/rlapoele/json-to-scss
- importing JSON into SASS/SCSS: https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer